# How to check the whether the given function is integrable or not

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Somedays ago i came across the question to integrate the function ∫sec(√(x))dx I checked it up by drawing the graph of the function my question is that can we check the integrability of the function without using the garphical method

Comment: The function is not integrable on any region containing any of the points $\left(\pm \frac{\pi}2 + 2\pi n \right)^2$.